# Add key and value to a returned scope array

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I need some insight. I am sendig data back to the controller from an ng-click="Info(c); I am then querying the database and returning all values from that array in my controller.

```
$scope.Info = function(user){   

    Data.get("Info/"+user.ID).then(function (data) {
        $scope.user = data.data;
        console.log(user);
    });
};
```

This will give me a return such as

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Data selected from database",
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": 32,
      "CountyID": 1,
      "Name": "tests",
      "PhoneNo": "(555)535-5555",
      "Address1": " industrial park"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to take that return and insert it into another table with more data. Basically add on the end of the returned data array city = 'New York' and state ='NY' so when I sent it back to the new table that has does two columns in it will populated them with the data from the $scope array.

```
"data": [
  {
    "ID": 32,
    "CountyID": 1,
    "Name": "tests",
    "PhoneNo": "(555)535-5555",
    "Address1": " industrial park",
    "City": "New York",
    "State": "NY"
  }
]
```

Right now it will just insert the columns that it has originally set from the data that is return by the get query.

I tried fallowing but it just will not add the two extra key's and values at the end of the user array.

```
angular.forEach($scope.user, function(obj){
    obj.push({'City' : 'New York'});
    obj.push({'State' : 'NY'});
});
```

or

```
user.push({"State":'NY'});
```

Please let me know how I can attached the two other values and have it sent to my Insert statement. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to add the city and state key/values to the end of the current user document. After `$scope.user = data.data`, you could add the properties to the object by doing the following:

```
$scope.user[0].city = "New York";
$scope.user[0].state = "NY";
```

Comment: yes that is correct. I want to add the city and state key/values to the end of the current user document. After $scope.user = data.data. Let me try what you are recomending. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add `city = 'New York' and state ='NY'` to the returned array, you can simply do this:

```
$scope.user.push({'city': 'New York'})
$scope.user.push({'state': 'NY'})
```

I may have misunderstood your question though.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the info. For some reason what ever I did it did not include my key's and values. I tried the push but with no luck. I then realized that I did one mistake I did it outside the Data.get function and so it never even saw my changes. After I fixed my function and used js91 solution I got it to work.

Here is what I ended up doing

```
 $scope.newInfo = function(user){
     Data.get("Info/"+user.ID).then(function (data) {
         $scope.x = data.data;
         $scope.x[0].city = 'New York';
         $scope.x[0].state = 'NY';
         console.log($scope.x);

         Data.post('dealerAudit', $scope.x[0]).then(function(result){

         });
     });
 };
```